# Turn on / off screensaver with Java

Tags: java, windows

Can I use Java (which is already running a large amount of code) to turn on the screen saver, and then, when a certain trigger happens,   Turn the screen saver off? Preferably in Windows 10

Comment: I hesitate to suggest it, since it's complicated, but you can always do pretty much anything on your target platform using JNI.

Comment: I mean what you could do is setting the delay right in Windows (for the screensaver) and if it is finished you trigger something (e.g. move the mouse with awt.Robot)

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I've managed toget the Screen Saver to turn on and off using Java Process Builder, and then calling.start() when I want to activate theScreen Saver.